# How to draw a big hollow diamond in GLES on phone?

Tags: android, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I want to render a very large hollow diamond. In the fragment shader, if a point is inside the diamond, it is not rendered, otherwise it is rendered. The program runs very well on PC, but it does not work on Android phones. I guess it should be caused by accuracy problems. The size of the rhombus is changed. Sometimes it is too large, exceeding the mediump value in GLSL. Is there any other way to simply render a hollow diamond on the phone screen? The main code is as below:

```
uniform mediump vec4 user_DiamondCenter;
uniform mediump vec4 user_DiamondSize;
varying mediump vec4 v_worldPos;

lowp vec4 fragmentColor = v_fragmentColor;
lowp vec4 srcColor = texture2D(CC_Texture0, v_texCoord);
mediump vec4 testPoint = (v_worldPos - user_DiamondCenter);
lowp float fIn = step(user_DiamondSize.y * user_DiamondSize.x * 0.5f, abs(testPoint.x * user_DiamondSize.y) + abs(testPoint.y * user_DiamondSize.x));
fragmentColor.a = fragmentColor.a * fIn;
gl_FragColor = fragmentColor * srcColor;
```

The user_DiamondSize may be very large, so it cause the problem. Is there any solution, or any other simple way to render this large hollow diamond? The camera is moving, and sometimes it is necessary to render the border of this diamond.

Comment: Have you tried using highp instead of mediump. Not all GLES2 devices support highp in the fragment shader so it is far from a complete fix, but it should reduce the number of affected devices.

Answer (score 1):

If the camera is within the object, and the object is not rendered only on phone, then the obvious issue is in Face culling.

```
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)
```

This will disable culling so you can check if that is the issue